# Cross Account access in Alibaba Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Following is the documentation for AWS switch role - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

What is the equivalent of this available for Alibaba Cloud ?

The goal is to use something similar in Alibaba cloud so that the credentials obtained from the assumed role can be used to create / access resources in another account based on the permissions given to that role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AssumeRole functionality is available in Alibaba Cloud, Details can be accessed on [AssumeRole](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/28763.htm)

Answer (score -1):

It could have solutions for cross account access. usually in two scenes

1. personal account, you could just create one RAM role for him. it could be faster.
2. company account, you could add different company account in your enterprises. they will be one of the member , then it is ok for cross access.